# How can we achieve animations in playN

Tags: animation, playn

I need to create some simple effects for the layers which I have created in my playN game. For instance, a layer starts as a line, resize on update, and thus slowly expands to full screen. Can I use triple play for this? 
For example: we can use `setAlpha` in update function to make a fading effect.

Comment: I dont know why people are voting down questions without having a good look at it or before dropping a comment to improve the question. We ask question here to get some answers, but if you vote it down, it is less likely to be answered. Thanks..

Comment: Usually a question like this gets the good kind of attention if you provide some source code to demonstrate how you've tried to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the `Animator` class from tripleplay, does exactly that

code snippet:

```
class MyGame extends Game {
    private Animator anim;
    private float _elapsed = 0;

    public void init() {
        anim = Animator.create();

        anim.tweenScale(aLayer).from(0).to(50).linear();
    }

    public void paint(float alpha) {
        anim.update(_elapsed + alpha * updateRate());
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        _elapsed += delta;
    }
}
```